# What is this wall covering in our 1908 USA house?

Tags: walls, plaster, asbestos, old-house

We are working on a house built in 1908 in the USA and have found what a local old-timer called “deadening felt” attached to the walls and ceilings, which are shiplap. The internet returns no images that match our deadening felt from the era. Whatever it is, it looks as if it has a number of layers (all the different colors) and that it was painted right onto. There may be a very thin skim coat of plaster on there...or just years of paint. You can see the vertical seams on the walls where it abuts/overlaps the same material. It has not molded even though we are in a wet climate. We found this post on stack exchange as a clue, but it doesn’t quite match what we have: [Proper way to repair old plasterboard walls?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/215330/proper-way-to-repair-old-plasterboard-walls) .

Does anyone know what this type of wall covering is? All of the samples came back *negative* for asbestos. How do folks typically remove this covering, or do they?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd recommend a different search engine because google returned dozens of hits including this ad: https://www.periodpaper.com/products/1915-ad-hydrex-saniflor-sound-proof-deadening-felt-flooring-construction-diagram-071739-arc3-317

Comment: The plaster might have asbestos and/or the paint might have lead, take precautions(wear a mask) if removing and causing dust.  The deadening felt is probably just felt(or similar) to reduce noise transfer.  Unless removing it to repair the walls, might be better to just place drywall over it.

Comment: We did take precautions, thank you! 

Search engine works fine; that is an ad for felt floor underlayment from after the house was built, and it's only on the walls and ceilings.

Comment: Sorry. When someone says "The internet returns nothing for deadening felt!" and a google search returns 40K results my assumption is it's their search engine that is the problem. Especially when it's a product that is still being made.

Comment: Can you be more specific about exactly which thing in those pictures you're talking about? In the first pic, there's the tan/grey (with water stains), there's the pink stuff, there's the dark grey/black patch. Those repeat in the 2nd and 3rd images with the addition of some wood. Which color item are you referring to?

Comment: Ah, yes - the pictures are of the same material, which has layers. The photo with the wood is a cross-section where the wood is "shiplap" wall of the house.